# I am working with the github api with vuejs. I have an issue with loading images from the api. The images are not loading properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuejs3

After one searches for a GitHub user, the api is meant to respond with some data like the image, username, repo of the user etc. But I am having issues with the way the image of the user is being displayed on the browser, apart from the image displayed, there are 5 other duplicates of the image showing vertically downwards and I do not know why that is so.

```
<template>
    <div>
    ...
     <p> 
     <img
         class="avatar"
          v-for="(info, key) in infos"  :key="key"
           :src="info.avatar_url"
           />
           </p>
    </div>
    </template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",

 data(){
    return{
       name: '',
       infos: null,
     }
    
 },
    
 
  methods:{

    hello(){
       let user= document.querySelector(".search").value;
       let fullname = user.split(" ").join("");
       let msg = "No Username Found";
    
     const axios= require("axios");
  axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+fullname)
            .then(response => (this.infos = response))
            .catch(error => alert(error +" " +msg));
            },
  
    reset(){
       this.name="";
       
 }
      }
};

</script>
```

Comment: Please show your work

Comment: How do you call the api? please share the script

Comment: Yea, I have adjusted the code now the script tag is included.